# How can I Style the ArcGIS TimeSlider

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

How can I customize the TimeSlider provided with ArcGIS API for WPF. Is it possible to access the Play button in the TimeSlider.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty simple. You can open the your project in Expression Blend and go to the `TimeSlider` in the project Navigator in the left hand side, then right click on it and choose edit Template. Choose Create a Copy and then you can see the Style of the `TimeSlider` in the XAML file. You will find `PlayPauseToggleButton` in the Style.